# Constructors are not inherited but behaving strangely

Tags: java

I have found this issue and I do not understand why constructors are being inherited in the first case. 
As far as I know, constructors are not inherited. Am I missing something very important ?

```
class Bird {
{ System.out.print("b1 ");}
public Bird() {System.out.print("b2 ");}

class Raptor extends Bird
{
    static {System.out.print("r1 ");}

    public Raptor() {System.out.print("r2 ");}

    {
        { System.out.print("r3 ");}
        static {System.out.print("r4 ");}
    }

class Hawk extends Raptor 
{    
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {    
        System.out.print("pre ");
        new Hawk();
        System.out.println("hawk ");
    }
}
```

The answer for the above is:

r1 r4 pre b1 b2 r3 r2 hawk

Comment: Clean up your formatting and be more specific about what you're trying to demonstrate.

Comment: That looks logical. What is the question? What do you not understand?

Comment: I asked how did the output come

Answer (score 1):

If you don't explicitly call the parent class constructor (via `super(...)`) or another constructor from the same class (via `this(...)`), the 0-argument parent class constructor is implicitly called.

Specifically, your code `public Raptor() {System.out.print("r2 ");}` implicitly calls the `Bird` constructor as the first thing, as if you had typed `public Raptor() {super(); System.out.print("r2 ");}`

Works similarly for your `Hawk` subclass.

Comment: Thanks Elliot - updated